# Write into the SQLite database from an Android service in Delphi (RAD Studio)

Tags: android, sqlite, delphi, android-service, firemonkey

I have an Android application and service in the same process. Write code under RAD Studio Delphi 10.1.

I need to get geographic coordinates in Android Service (that I'm doing well) and write them to the SQLite database.
And from time to time the application can (when the user needs) process the coordinates in the user interface.

When I put TConnection (any - ADO, FireDAC, UniDAC) into DataModule not even make an active connection, the service stops working, even not running the OnStartCommand event.

Monitor.bat shows no obvious errors.

Please tell me how to work with a SQLite database in Android Service and it Android Application at the same time.

Comment: If you are wanting your Sqlite to be on the Android device, you'd need an edition of Sqlite that runs on Android, if one exists.  ADO is Windows-only afaik, btw.  Another way might be to write a Windows-hosted REST server and have your Android app write to that.

Comment: So what can I do if main application closed, but it's service is running? If I send message from service to application (like Intent or someone else), the application will run, and I don't want it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution:

I updated UniDAC components for Berlin to latest version (6.3.12).

TUniConnection and TUniQuery well work with SQLite in Android Service.

Add to Project->Deployment of the host application my SQLite DB-file, Remote Path sets to ".\assets\internal\".

I hope this code will useful for you.

```
procedure TDM.conSQLiteBeforeConnect(Sender: TObject);
begin
{$IF DEFINED(iOS) or DEFINED(ANDROID)}
  conSQLite.Database := TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'mybase.sqlite');
{$ENDIF}
end;

procedure TDM.conSQLiteError(Sender: TObject; E: EDAError; var Fail: Boolean);
begin
  Log('--- DB error: %s:', [E.Message]);
  Fail := False;
end;

function TDM.AndroidServiceStartCommand(const Sender: TObject; const Intent: JIntent; Flags, StartId: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Log('+ START with Intent: ' + JStringToString(Intent.getAction.toString), []);
  if Intent.getAction.equalsIgnoreCase(StringToJString('StopIntent')) then
  begin
    try
      conSQLite.Disconnect;
      Log('- DB disconnected', []);
    except
      on E: Exception do
        Log('- can not to disconnect DB', [E.Message]);
    end;

    Log('... service to be stoped', []);
    JavaService.stopSelf;

    Result := TJService.JavaClass.START_NOT_STICKY; // don't reload service
  end
  else
  begin
    Log('... service started', []);

    try
      conSQLite.Connect;
      Log('+ DB connected', []);

      UniQuery.SQL.Text := 'select count(*) as ALLREC from orders';
      UniQuery.Open;
      if UniQuery.RecordCount > 0 then
      begin
        UniQuery.First;
        Log('... record count: %s', [UniQuery.FieldByName('ALLREC').AsString]);
      end;
      UniQuery.Close;
    except
      on E: Exception do
        Log('- can not to connect DB: %s', [E.Message]);
    end;

    Result := TJService.JavaClass.START_STICKY; // rerun service if it stops
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have struggled the same issue but I started to use TSQLConnection (dbexpress) component with TSQLQuery (dbexpress) component and these are components wrok well in Android service.

Comment: Good news. Which version of RAD Studio do you use?

Comment: I use Delphi 10.1 Berlin but it was work on Delphi 10 Seattle also.